# SSDT and vs2010: Can I work on database projects without importing?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-2012-datatools

Whenever I Import I find lots of errors that since the database hasn't been worked with this tool, we did not have to fight case sensitive issues, nor views with unreferenced tables and a lot of other stuff that didn't worry us when we were on DevEnv.

Beacuse of this, I resolved to  try working somewhat disconnected as a transitional state. but without loosing the TFS code repo or issue tracker.

Is it possible to work on sqlprojects and be able to validate and deploy code without having to import the database into the proj?

If it is, how?

@Edit:
Ok, so I've been asked to maintain the self DB reference inside the queries from within SP's, since DTSs execute some of those SP's, and it should evaluate the references without error.

(*I'll be posting more stuff.*)

Comment: Have you used the older DB Projects and are trying to upgrade to SQL Projects or is this your first attempt at getting your database into a project structure? If this is your first time, you'll need to resolve issues at first, but once you're past that it gets easier. If you can give some more details, I can try to give better direction.

Comment: Hi again! No it's the first attempt. You would like more details on the errors? or on what I am trying to do?

Comment: That would help. Start with what you're trying to do, then give us some details on errors. I know when we started out, we had a bunch of errors for DB self-references, missing references to other DBs, and so on. It took a while to fix/clean everything, but once we got through that initial pain, it worked pretty well.